# Can we query State and Country/Territories Picklist via SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, picklist, country-and-state, global-picklist

We need to check the validations manually in Batch Apex while creating SF Accounts?

We have a scenario where we store all the data in our Custom Object (brought the data from the third party).

In a nightly batch, we will map them to the Salesforce Accounts based on the Name or email. If there is no match, we will create a new SF Account.

It's working fine for those who haven't enabled this setting.

The main issue was, Country and States were returned in their short forms like CA for California.

So before populating the values to SF Account, we would like to get the Integration value of the Country or State based on the shortcode.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to [use the metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_addresssettings.htm?search_text=state%20and%20country), but it looks like it's possible to check the State / Country picklist settings in an org.